# Handling Entity Framework SaveChanges() exceptions for cleanup

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-4

I have a File Repository library which handles the saving of files onto the server.  Along with saving the physical file, **a database entry is also recorded**.

Below is the insert method.

```
public DataFile InsertFile(string fileName, byte[] fileBytes)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(FileRepPath, fileName), fileBytes);

    DataFile dataFile = NewDataFile(
        fileName,
        fileBytes.Length
    );

    try
    {
        using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
        {
            context.DataFiles.Add(dataFile);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(FileRepPath, fileName));
        throw;
    }

    return dataFile;
}
```

If the database update fails, then I want to delete the file from the server.  I do this by catching ANY exception that occurs from the context operations and delete the file (and rethrowing the error so that it can bubble up).

Is this correct practice?  Should I be catching more specific exceptions?

Comment: This question asks how to catch all entity framework exceptions. http://forums.asp.net/t/1829033.aspx/1

Comment: Be aware that in case of a system failure you might still end up with the file on disk, but not have the record in the database.

Comment: In case of a concurrency exception or a unique constraint violation someone else may have added the `DataFile` just before the current user, so you don't want to delete the file from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) object to manage this task for you. Every component that implements the [IEnlistmentNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx) interface can participate in a two-phase commit of the `TransactionScope`.

The commit will require enlisting the services of MS-DTC but it will ensure all or nothing is saved. MS-DTC is used to co-ordinate the results of transactions across multiple heterogeneous resources.

Here are a couple of Microsoft articles:

- [Enhance Your Apps With File System Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx)
- [Transactional NTFS Managed Wrapper](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/txfmanaged)